# NHibernate: Is it possible to prevent optimistic dirty locking just for DELETE statements?

Tags: nhibernate

I have Nhb (ver. 3.3.3) mapping configuration like this

```
.Override<MyObject>(m =>
{
        m.LazyLoad();
        m.DynamicUpdate();
        m.OptimisticLock.Dirty();
...
}
```

dirty optimistic locking works fine with UPDATE statements but throws some exceptions like "Invalid index 80 for this SqlParameterCollection with Count=80." when I run DELETE statement for [MyObject]. One of the known reason for that is duplicated object properties in configuration mapping, but I have none duplicated. Is it possible to switch dirty locking off for DELETE statement leaving for UPDATE? I actually do not need optimistic locking for DELETE at all, I want it to be as simple as `DELETE from MyObject WHERE Id=12343`.

Answer (score 0):

You can supply your own DELETE SQL statement for NHibernate, but, at the moment, it is not supported in mapping by code. You can do something like this:

1. Create a Configuration and add your mappings
2. After you do that, locate the mapping for your entity as `cfg.ClassMappings.Single(x => x.EntityName == "MyEntity").SetCustomSQLDelete("DELETE FROM MyEntity WHERE Id = ?", true, ExecuteUpdateResultCheckStyle.Count);`

Comment: There is no such method as `SetCustomSQLDelete` in `FluentNHibernate.MappingModel.ClassBased.ClassMapping` and nothing similar, though I found `SqlDelete` method right in a mapping to "Specify an delete stored procedure", but it does not work, NHb keeps generating bulky WHERE statement instead as long as I have optimistic dirty locking in configuration.

Comment: Who mentioned FluentNHibernate? This method is from NHibernate's built in mapping by code, and works perfectly.

Comment: Ok, got it. I've just done exactly the same, rebuild solution and it still generates comprehensive WHERE statement for Delete operation. Seems like it just ignores this custom Sql delete settings in case of optimistic locking